# Deleting predefined high values from multi band raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm working with MOD-16-evapotranspiration and I have a problem. I made a composition 180 bands, but in this images I have  predefined high values(such as 32767, 32765..). So, I would like to hide this values for all 180 bands.
I'm working with QGIS software.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please, take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/253038/edit) your answer. You need to select which software are you using/asking. What have you tried so far? In QGIS you can use SCP; in ArcGIS, raster calculator; in ENVI, mask creation, and so on...

Comment: Tks aldo_tapia..I edited my question!!

Comment: Can you upload a sample data? a small crop could be great

Comment: What do you mean by "delete values"? You can't delete pixels from a raster. The best you can do is hide them...

Comment: aldo_tapia. So, I have only image (180 bands). This archive is .tif (109MB). Do you want me to send it?here I can send ?

Comment: Logan Byers. You are right. But, how I can hide them? Can I do it on some software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable using [`gdal_calc.py`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html), which should be accessible if you have Qgis installed.

The basic format of the `gdal_calc.py` call would be:

```
gdal_calc.py -A path_to_raster --allBands=A \
    --calc="A * (A < threshold) + nodata * (A >= threshold)" \
    --outfile=path_to_new_raster --NoDataValue=nodata
```

where:

`threshold` is a value above which the data will be hidden

`nodata` is the value that will be written to the masked pixels

The `calc` option may need to be more complex than this if you already have `NoData` values in the raster, but you should be able to understand the logic. The boolean results within the `calc` argument are essentially 1 and 0 which makes the multiplication work.

See also [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212495/set-one-output-bands-no-data-value-with-gdal-merge-py) which shows some more advance logic.

Comment: In this case I can't for example consider the nodata values = 0 or 1 (or other specific value) , because when I extract to average of bands, I will have problems (I extract the values in the software ENVI)...                            The ideal would be use NoDataValue=-999 but I don't know if can. I would need mask the values to that they do not enter in the average.       I already maked in the matlab a transformation to zero, but found this problem...

Comment: In GIS software, NODATA values are usually excluded from any raster calculation internally. You just have to tell the software which values to treat as NODATA. `gdal_translate -a_nodata` is one method to do so. You can use the raster calculator to merge several NODATA into one single value.